# Uncompressing file should use multithread or multiprocess?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, compression

I'm uncompressing `xz` files using `lzma` module in python

```
with lzma.LZMAFile(compressed_path, "rb") as in_f, open(output_path, "wb") as out_f:
    shutil.copyfileobj(in_f, out_f)
```

I'm trying to speed up multi-file uncompression in python, I've tried both:

- `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`(if it's IO-bound, multi-thread might help)
- `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`(if it's CPU bound, multi-process might help, regarding GIL).

But they turn out to be almost the same.

My understanding for uncompression is that it's more likely IO-bound, at least the computation is much less than compression. But if it's really IO-bound, the speed is still much slower than simply copying files.

So what's really happening behind uncompress, and how should I improve the speed?

Comment: This is very dependent of the target platform (HDD vs SSD, file system, OS, processor) and your archive (compression level, many small file VS few huge file). Multiprocessing should be the best option in general since it should not be significantly slower than multithreading if the operation is only IO-bound. That being said, multiprocessing is a bit less flexible (dependent of your needs).

Comment: And just confirming.  Your multithreading is via a function that takes `compressed_path` and `output_path` as arguments?

Comment: Instead of guessing, I suggest you try it both ways and compare results. Alternatively, you could profile your code and see where it's spending most of its time (to determine whether it's compute or I/O bound). See [How do I profile a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-do-i-profile-a-python-script)

Comment: Have you tried adding a `length` parameter of say 1024*1024 bytes to your `lzma.LZMAFile()`?

Comment: @FrankYellin yes that's what I'm trying with multithread, and the same as multi-process as well